# Python: No directory/ file when using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have simple code:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

open_workbook('Book1.xls')
```

No matter how I save the file (xls or xlsx) or how I change the path to the file (C:\Users\... or C:\Users...) I keep getting:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '(insert whatever is in place of Book1.xls)'
```

I don't know what I could be doing wrong. I'm not trying anything specific yet I just want it to not throw up an error.

Comment: is your script in the same directory as `Book1.xls`?

Comment: Actually this fixed it! thanks! does this always have to be the case even if you give it a full path to where it is?

Answer (score 3):

You are not including whole path of the file. The path will be looks like:

```
file="C:\\USER\\TEST\\FILENAME"
```

or

```
file=r":\USER\TEST\FILENAME"
```

If you are using single slash then you need to use 'r' or else it will throw error.

Comment: I was including the full path i just abbreviated for the question. but i did try the "r" thing and it still didnt work

Answer (score 1):

you are not doing `workbook("Book1.xls")`

you are passing it a path (with directories) ... one of the folders in the path doesnt exist

this is probably because you do something like

```
directory="C:\Users\Blah\..."
```

when you need to do

```
directory = r"C:\Users\Blah\..."
```

other wise the backslashes serve to escape the next character